# Downloading file using flask

Tags: python, web-services, flask

I see how to upload files using flask, and I have done so, but how do I do it if my client wants to download a file?

```
@app.route('/return-files',methods=['GET'])
def return_file():
    return send_from_directory(directory='uploads', filename=g, as_attachment=True)
```

[image: directory]

That is the image of the directory, I get the error:**Internal server error**

Comment: Pass debug = True to your app.run() call, you should get more detiled error then, also: from where your variable `g` comes from?

Answer (score 4):

You misunderstand the concept of filename, the filename should include file's extension, so the code should like this:

```
@app.route('/return-files', methods=['GET'])
def return_file():
    return send_from_directory(directory='uploads', filename='g.mp4', as_attachment=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Send File mthod instead

```
@app.route('/return-files', methods=['GET'])
def return_file():
      return send_file('./uploads', as_attachment=True, attachment_filename="g.mp4")
```